# roots written as exponents

Tags: calculus, roots

It appears that i'm not quite sure anymore how to write roots as exponents, and how to work with them.
I know $\sqrt[3]{a}$ is written $a^{\frac{1}{3}}$, but I don't know how to handle them in things like fractures ($\frac{a^{\frac{1}{3}}}{a}$ appears to be $\frac{1}{a^\frac{2}{3}}$), or what to think of when seeing something like $a^\frac{2}{3}$

It would be nice if you could give me a brief, but as complete as possible description on this :)

thank you.

Comment: $a^{\frac{m}{n}}$ is just ${}^n\sqrt{a^m}$.

Comment: Take $m=1=n$ and $a=-1$.
$(-1)^{\frac{2}{2}} = (-1)^1 = -1$
whereas $\sqrt{(-1)^{2}} = \sqrt{1} = 1$

Comment: @KevinCarlson: You can typeset a non-square root with `\sqrt[n]{a^m}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{a^{1/3}}{a}=a^{1/3-1}=a^{-2/3}=(a^{2/3})^{-1}=\frac{1}{a^{2/3}}$

Hope this helps!

Comment: makes perfect sense. though still ~ is there a way to think of it as a root?

Comment: Exactly as Kevin Carlson says :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, you have $x^{\frac{a}{b}}=(\sqrt[b]{x})^{a}$ for positive integers $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\geq0$.

Comment: i wasn't (even) aware of the fact that $\sqrt[b]{x^a} = \sqrt[b]{x}^a$... jeez i really got a problem with my basics x.x